# What is the most efficient way to get a negative lookbehind to work alongisde an optional value?

Tags: regex, option-type, icu, negative-lookbehind

I'm aware negative look-behinds have to be  zero width but I've noticed an issue where they don't work if the preceding token is optional. Why does this happen?

```
(?<!test):?(\\d{3})
```

Fails on `test123`.
But passes `test:123`

Is there a solution to this other than `(?<!test|test:)`? I'd rather avoid the above solution as the regex I'd like to apply this to already has a lot of negative look-behind phrases which I'd be doubling.

*Edit: I initially posted this using a PCRE editor but I'm coding with ICU*

Comment: I use a PCRE online tester for my ICU expressions then just add the extra backslashes so either is good for me. I get the same results in my swift ICU regex and the PCRE web app. The web app's just much easier to share and experiment with.

Comment: With ICU, you can use `(?<!test:{0,1})\d{3}`.

Comment: That works, thanks. That's the first difference other than the extra backslash I've come across. I should probably find an ICU editor.
Feel free to put that as an answer I'll edit the question to remove the PCRE references to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Note that ICU regex does not work the same as PCRE, you should be aware of the differences when testing in an incompatible environment, such as regex101.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the ICU regex engine, you have an access to a *constrained-width* lookbehind that allows using *limiting quantifiers of known length* inside the lookbehinds.

So, use

```
(?<!test:{0,1})\d{3}
        ^^^^^^
```

The `:{0,1}` will match one or zero `:`.

Note that [ICU regex](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) does not work the same as [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/), you should be aware of the differences when testing in an incompatible environment, such as [regex101.com](http://regex101.com).

Some cool PCRE features that are missing in ICU:

- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs
- `\K` operator

Some cool ICU features missing in PCRE:

- Constrained width-lookbehind (`(?<!test:{0,1})\d{3}`)
- Character class intersection (`[\p{Letter}&&\p{script=cyrillic}]`) or subtraction (`[\p{Letter}--\p{script=latin}]`)